# MFP 7.1 - Message counter on Worklight console does not work

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

The message counter in Worklight console(Check the screen shot) does not increase if [Send Message (POST)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_message_post.html?lang=en) from [REST API Runtime Services](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/c_restapi_runtime.html?lang=en) is used to send push. What is an issue with that, do I need to do any configuration modification to make this work?[image]

Comment: Did you mean does NOT work?

Comment: Thats Right. I mean it does not work

Comment: The screenshot shows 2 messages against eventsource. Please confirm if you see count increment when using submitNotification.

Comment: Right! When I use submitNotification message counter does work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a defect in the product, to have it investigated you will need to open a service call (PMR) and await a responsive from the development team, whether this is indeed a defect.

If you say that when using the REST API, the 'messages' counter does not increase, but if using the adapter API it does increase, then that would be a defect...